# Sklearn yellowbrick classification_report could not decode y values into labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, multiclass-classification, yellowbrick

I'm following this example from `tsfresh`: [Multiclass](https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/blob/main/notebooks/04%20Multiclass%20Selection%20Example.ipynb) . It is a classification example using feature extraction and a decision tree classifier.

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from tsfresh import extract_features, extract_relevant_features, select_features
from tsfresh.utilities.dataframe_functions import impute
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from tsfresh.examples.har_dataset import download_har_dataset, load_har_dataset, load_har_classes
download_har_dataset()
df = load_har_dataset()
y = load_har_classes()
df["id"] = df.index
df = df.melt(id_vars="id", var_name="time").sort_values(["id", "time"]).reset_index(drop=True)
X = extract_features(df[df["id"] < 500], column_id="id", column_sort="time", impute_function=impute)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y[:500], test_size=.2)
classifier_full = DecisionTreeClassifier()
classifier_full.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Now I am trying to visualize the classification report using:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_occupancy
from yellowbrick.classifier import classification_report
classes=np.unique(y)
classes=classes.tolist()
classes=list(map(str,classes))
visualizer = classification_report(GaussianNB(), X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, classes=classes, support=True)
```

However when running the script, it gives:
`ModelError: could not decode [1 2 3 4 5 6] y values to [1 2 3 4 5 6] labels`

Anyone knows why it happens?

I tried comparing with this example: [Scikit classification example](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/classifier/classification_report-2.py), where I found the classification_report, and I think the problem is in the data structure, but I can't find any difference? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `y` seems to be used as an index into `classes`.  I don't know the best way to handle that since `y` starts at `1` and python `list` index start is `0`.  One hack that I'm not competent to assess is, but still allows `classification_report` to run, is to insert `classes.insert(0,None)` just before `visualizer = ...`  I suppose you could decrement all `y` values by `1`, and then _everything should just run_, YMMV.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!  Decrementing all values of `y` by 1 and changing the classes to `[0 1 2 3 4 5]` were enough. I forgot that indexes start at 0 in Python :).